# running nivo slider from inside .load content

Tags: jquery, bind, jquery-load, nivo-slider

im loading some content into a div using .load and but im having a little trouble getting nivo slider to run as part of the loaded content. I think its somthing to do with binding but im not realy sure..

at the moment im uisng this for the .load

```
google.load("jquery", "1.6.2");

google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
$("#pegasus-tile, #o-w").click(function(){
    $("#proj-content").load("projects/pegasus.html")
    });
});
```

and this for the nivo slider

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('#slider, #slider2').nivoSlider();
});
```

is there a simple way to get this to work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't intialize the slider unitl the html exists for it. To do this you need to intialize it within the success callback of ajax. You need to change your ajax load() method as follows

```
    $("#proj-content").load("projects/pegasus.html", function(){
                /* new html exists here*/
                $('#slider, #slider2').nivoSlider();
    });
```

Comment: thanks, just a quick question, so the new html would be the content thats being loaded ? because that already exists in the projects/pegasus.html file

Comment: the new html means the html that is being loaded into current page from the pegaus file.... can't run most plugin code in a page on elements that don't exist...until they exist

Comment: ahh ok, might be a silly question but if you put it in there why need the pegasus.html file at all ?

Comment: no idea what you mean... pegasus is your source for the html, keep in mind only part of your page you've show is one ajax load, have no idea what your situation is

Comment: right, so its just the html for the slider, like this  <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
<img src="images/projects/pegasus property/1.png" width="490" height="400" />
<img src="images/projects/pegasus property/2.png" width="490" height="400" />
</div><!--slider close-->  (sorry for being a bit thick with this)

Comment: did you try what I gave you?  Make sure include plugin file on main page also